# R Markdown HTML output - Hide a section of the document of an HTML RMarkdown output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to knit an HTML document from `RMarkdown`, and **hide** the **section** from both the **Table of Contents** (ToC) and **body** of the output (HTML file), while while still knitting (executing) all of the code and contents.

I'm not looking to hide just the code **chunk** - this can be done through `echo = FALSE`.

I tried using the `{.hidden}` option meant for [flexdashboards](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#page_links) but it only *partially* solves the problem, i.e. the whole section (called `# The section I want to hide` in the example below) **disappears** from the HMTL *output* itself, but *not* the **table of contents**.

Code example:

````
---
output: 
  html_document: 
    df_print: kable
    fig_height: 2
    fig_width: 2
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE,
                      cache = FALSE,
                      dpi = 75,
                      comment = '')
```


# R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

# Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

# The section I want to hide {.hidden}

Super-secret text (section content I don't want to show).

```{r}
sumCars <- summary(cars)
```


# This the section I want to show again

```{r}
sumCars[1,]
```
````

---

Output:

[HTML output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnynM.png)

---

How can I hide the document section while still knitting?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me: is it text in between code chunks you want to hide, or an actual code chunk? Or both? The code chunk you can simply hide by using `include = FALSE` as chunk option. It still gets evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by using  `.unlisted .unnumbered`

`# The section I want to hide {.hidden .unlisted .unnumbered}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use arbitrary css in markdown when exporting to html. Here is an example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

# One

Hello!

# Two

<style>
 #two {
   display: none;
 }
</style>

```{r}
x <- 1:10
```

# Three

```{r}
plot(x)
```
````

Comment: An associated question: How to hide the title section?

Comment: @LazarusThurston You can hide the title the same way -- use CSS to set `display: none;`

Comment: Your solution doesn't hide the section from the ToC.

Comment: @kategorically you can use my approach to hide the toc entry too, you just have to find the css identifier and set display to none

Answer (score 1):

The `unlisted` class ensures that a heading is not included in the table of contents, and `hidden` will hide a section in HTML output. Therefore, the following should work:

```markdown
# The section I want to hide {.hidden .unlisted}
```

Comment: Doesn't work currently (`knitr 1.45`) - any other suggestions? :)